# Finding sample space and outcome

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have 2 red candies, 3 blue candies, 4 pink candies inside a bowl. Candies of the same colour are **indistinguishable**. Then I randomly select one candy and record its colour. What is the sample space and how many outcomes does it have?

Would the sample space be {red, blue, pink}? Or would it be {red, red, blue,....,pink} having 9 elements in the sample space?

Would there be 3 outcomes? Or 9 outcomes?

Comment: There are 3 outcomes, but they are not equiprobable.

Comment: What would be the probability of drawing a red candy? I know it is $$\frac{2}{9}$$. But is the probability not $$\frac{coloured candy}{outcome}$$? Or am I confusing outcome with something else.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{2}{9}$. Not sure what your second fraction means - what are the two numbers? You have a variable X = "The colour drawn", which takes 3 values and a probability for each value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singleton subsets sets $\{R\}, \{B\}, \{K\}$ of sample space $S =\{R,G.K\}$ need not be assigned equal probabilities. Here you could have
$P(\{R\}) = 2/9,$ $P(\{B\}) = 3/9,$ $P(\{K\})= 4/9.$
Then you could find probabilities such as
$P(\mathrm{not\, R}) = 1 - 2/9 = 7/9$ and
$P(\mathrm{Red\,or\,Blue}) = 2/0 + 3/9 = 5/9,$ by
using the axioms of probability.

Alternatively, even though the candies of the same color
are not distinguishable, you could imagine they
are numbered in invisible ink. Then you could have
sample space $S_2 = \{r_1. r_2, b_1,b_2,b_3,k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4\},$ and assign each singleton
event probability $1/9: P(\{b_1\}) = 1/9, \dots,$
$P(\{k_4\}) = 1/9.$

Then $P(\mathrm{Blue}) =1/9 + 1/9 + 1/9 = 3/9 = 1/3.$

If you had an ultraviolet lamp that allows you to read the invisible ink, you could say
$P(\mathrm{Invisible\, number\ 3}) = 2/9.$